# site google tag does not show all results

Tags: search, robots.txt

If I go to this url 
http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/robots.txt

I get

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: 
Allow: /
```

That means that crawlers are allowed to fully access the website and index everything, then why site:sppp.rajasthan.gov.in on google search shows me only a few pages, where it contains lots of documents including pdf files.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a lot of reasons for that.

1. You don't need a robots.txt for blanket allowing crawling. Everything is allowed by default.
2. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html doesn't allow blank `Disallow` lines:

   > Also, you may not have blank lines in a record, as they are used to delimit multiple records.
3. Check google webmasters tools to see if some pages have been dissallowed for crawling.
4. Submit a sitemap to google.
5. Use "Fetch as google" to see if google can even see the site properly.
6. Try manually submitting a link through the fetch as google interface.

Looking closer at it.

1. Google doesn't know how to navigate some of the links on the site. Specifically http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/bidlist.php the bottom navigation uses `onclick` javascript that gets dynamically loaded and it doesn't change the URL so google couldn't link to page 2 it even if it wanted to.
2. On the bidlist you can click into a bid list detailing the tender. These don't have public URLs. Google has no way of linking into them.
3. The PDFs I looked at were image scans in sanskrit put into PDF documents. While Google does OCR PDF documents (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.sg/2011/09/pdfs-in-google-search-results.html) it's possibly they can't do it with sanskrit. You'd be more likely to fidn them if they contained proper text as opposed to images.

My original points remain though. Google should be able to find http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/sppp/upload/documents/5_GFAR.pdf which is on the http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/actrulesprocedures.php page. If you have a question about why a specific page might be missing, I'll try to answer it.

But basically the website does some bizarre non-standard things, this is exactly what you need a sitemap for. Contrary to popular belief sitemaps are **not** for SEO, it's for when google can't locate your pages.